# VirtualHost w/ NameVirtualHost

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am converting all my current VirtualHost configurations from being declared by ip to being declared by name (w/ NameVirtualHost set).

For this:

```
<VirtualHost www.test.com>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.test.com/        
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Do I need the ServerAlias or the ServerName? Will it still work without the www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set **ServerName**. ServerAlias just allows you to set aliases for the host.

```
<VirtualHost www.test.com>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.test.com/        
    ServerName www.test.com
    ServerAlias test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just to confirm... "h t t p : //test.com" WILL work without the ServerAlias declaration?

Comment: Whoops, missed it. ServerAlias **is** required in your case with multiple sites, you will need to configure the DNS A records for both www.test.com and test.com

Comment: Nope not local... ok I will just leave all the ServerAlais in there. Yes there is multiple sites on this one box.

Comment: When configuring the DNS records make sure both point to the same IP.